# Can Shared Access Signatures + Policies + $log data be used to enforce storage quotas?

Tags: security, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azcopy

I'm exploring if I can use the [Azure Storage $logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/storage-analytics-log-format) in conjunction with an [Access Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1#controlling-a-sas-with-a-stored-access-policy) to create and enforce end user quotas.  The Access policy will allow me to terminate new sessions that are invalid for whatever reason.

This question is primarily about active connections, since I'm pretty sure there is no issue or risk with non streaming data.

Assuming that I'm aggressively reading the $logs, and disable Shared Access Signatures once a threshold is reached, what "missing data" would there be for exploitation?

For example:

- Are open / in progress uploads or downloads logged? (I can't audit what I can't yet see)
- Once a policy is revoked, are the associated sessions terminated? (They can upload, download, or perhaps seek within the stream)
- Can I read a log that is "open" by the Azure logging service and keep somewhat up-to-date metrics?

My assumption is that none of this occurs, and even with an Access Policy, there are several avenues for abuse.

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by "exploitation"? Do you mean if a user can still continue to fetch data even after you have disabled the SAS?

Comment: @GauravMantri In this scenario, assume it's a large download that the user shared the key with several hundred/thousand people.  This egress is billable, and indicative of a ToS violation (copyright, or other term relevant to the data at hand)

Comment: So, as soon as you invalidate a SAS any operation done using that SAS will result in 403 error from that point on. Assuming your download is implemented in chunks, in this case users will get partial data. Does this answer your question?

Comment: @GauravMantri That answers bullet two.  But I'm not sure if I get in-flight data... or if I can require that all data is downloaded in chunks.

Comment: I think SAS works more like a gatekeeper. It gets validated when a request reaches Azure Storage. So assuming you have a request that takes say 15 seconds to process. When the request reaches Azure Storage, SAS is validated. If it is valid then the service starts processing the data. Now while the service is still processing the data, you invalidate the SAS. In this case the request will succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are open / in progress uploads or downloads logged? (I can't audit what I can't yet see)

As I known, operations against Azure Storage Service are based on Storage Service REST API. Here is the detailed operations that are logged for the corresponding storage service, you could refer to this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/storage-analytics-logged-operations-and-status-messages).

> Once a policy is revoked, are the associated sessions terminated? (They can upload, download, or perhaps seek within the stream)

I have tried to upload my large file to Azure Blob with SAS & Access Policies, when I revoked the policy then the subsequent uploading request would be interrupted and return 403 as follows:

[image]

For downloading large file, if the request reaches Azure Storage Service and the authentication is passed, then I revoked the policy. At this point, the pre-authenticated downloading request would continue and the file would be downloaded successfully. All my tests completely correspond with Gaurav Mantri's comments.

> Can I read a log that is "open" by the Azure logging service and keep somewhat up-to-date metrics?

Per my understanding, we could leverage [Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer](http://storageexplorer.com/) to retrieve Storage Analytic Log files for a simple way. We could download the log file and verify the detailed requests. As I known, there is no any in-build features or tools which could read Storage Analytic Log and keep your opened log content somewhat up-to-date.

Comment: Thank you, would you know the minimum logging needed to obtain the information? (there are 3 settings I recall none, basic, debug - or something to that effect)

Comment: As I known, for storage account (modern), you could enable "Blob logs" option under "MONITORING > Diagnostics" to log detailed requests for Blob Storage. For storage account (classic), you could log "Read Requests" or "Write Requests" or "Delete Requests" for Storage Services under "Configure > logging" section of your storage account in old portal. If I misunderstand your idea, please illustrate your doubt.